# Building an waveshaper device for my analog synth

Tags: converter, line, phase-shift

I have a nice analog synthesizer that can do fancy sounds but has limited options in shaping the tone. It has two oscillators but they don't output sine waves (low pass filtering is not an option in many cases). It also lacks a high pass filter.

Because I'd like to get a specific waveform my idea is to build something like a guitar stomp box which gets fed with only a basic saw wave from the line output of my synthesizer. The box should split this signal into 3 paths:

[image: desired output forms of the split paths]

1. input signal unchanged
2. input signal inverted and time delayed by a fixed value about 200 µs (would be nice to have a trimpot to vary the time from about 170–230 µs)
3. input signal's saw converted to a sine

The mix of such signals would give a waveform that's similar to one that can be heard in many techno tracks like e. g. "Satisfaction" by Benny Benassi

As my understanding of electric engineering is rather poor, can you tell me if this is a task that can be accomplished by beginner? Or would it be a too complex circuit requiring good calculation skills? The circuit should be capable of notes playing fundamental frequencies of down to about 32 Hz. The high cutoff of the synth is at about 20kHz (4 pole).

What I have found instructions for already is [this](http://www.circuitstoday.com/3-channel-audio-splitter) 3 channel line level splitter circuit, and also [this](https://www.muffwiggler.com/forum/userpix/2077_sawtosine_shaper_2.jpg) schematic for a saw to sine converter.

I guess path 2 could be made flipping its output terminals and using a 555 timer for the phase shift but don't know how to connect it.

Answer (score 1):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f1dxxd.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>
The attached circuit will allow you to vary AC phase shift from 0 to 170 degrees.
you would have to experiment and test it, as I'm not sure what affect the distortion caused by such a circuit would have on the audio effect your after.
Hope this is some help.
It's good to see someone doing some homework before asking the forums!
Ben.

Comment: Usually, shifting phase by degrees is right for audio purposes. But for my purpose, the shift shouldn't be dependant on the actual note being played. When signal 1 gets mixed with signal 2, a (nearly) flat cycle with only a narrow pulse will result. I'd like to have this pulse at a fixed width, so the "edge" of the sound doesn't get narrower when playing higher notes, nor wider when playing lower notes. But thank you very much for the schematic! Not quite the solution but good for my learning. Having got in touch to electronics by hobby, there is plenty of upcoming homework, I guess

Comment: I'm sorry! Didn't notice I had used the word "phase" initially, which you correctly answered on. A phase delay can only be given in degrees, right? My fault..